# Dragging Jlabel images between two JPanels

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, drag-and-drop, jpanel

To help better understand how we want the program to function here is a list of what we have so far:

- 1 JPanel that has a background floor plan image that functions as the
  “whiteboard” that the user will place objects on.
- 1 JPanel that holds all of the buttons and controls functionality of
  a selected object in the “whiteboard” panel
- 1 JPanel that is placed in a JScrollPanel that holds a list of
  JLabels with images to be placed on the “whiteboard” panel
- A class of objects that stores all the properties for each type of
  furniture item that can be placed; such as x/y cords, image location,
  price, labor cost, etc

What we would like to happen is the following:

1. A user “Mouse Presses and Holds” on a JLabel in the scroll list panel (I assume the JLables will need to be made selectable somehow also)
2. The event then takes the name of the JLabel
3. Instantiates an object of the item class based on the name
4. Adds that object to an array of items in the “whiteboard” panel
5. Then loads a copy of a different image based on the location in the object’s properties
6. Then attaches that image to the mouse cursor
7. As long as the user is holding the mouse button down the image will stay attached
8. If the user then releases the mouse button inside the “whiteboard” panel area, an event will be triggered to set the object’s location to the coordinates of the mouse cursor
9. If the mouse is released anywhere else, the cursor returns to the default windows one, and the JLabel Remains selected

I don't know if it would be simpler to set up a mouse listener that binds an image to the mouse and then places a copy of it onto the whiteboard wherever it is clicked.

Here is a link to an image of what has been created so far: http://img824.imageshack.us/img824/4083/o50p.png

[image]

Any tips or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Look into using Swing's drag & drop functionality as it could work well for you.

Comment: The question depends.  Do you want to use the drag'n'drop API, which is very powerful but has a minor drawback (visual feedback) or roll your own, using something like the glass pane

Comment: A possible [example of both](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11460704/dragging-a-jlabel-with-a-transferhandler-drag-and-drop/11462364#11462364) - check both answers

Answer (score 0):

I would have to say use a `JToolBar`. I say this because it has built-in drag'n'drop. If you wanted, you could do this manually using Mouse Listeners and `java2d`. just put the `JLabel` images inside a `JToolBar`. good luck!